# Validar clave que sólo tenga tres dígitos con una expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo que crear una clave controlada por una expresión regular con una serie de características. Tiene que tener al menos:

- una letra mayúscula,
- una minúscula,
- una acentuada,
- un signo de euro, asterisco o dolar (una de ellas, no las tres)
- 3 dígitos (ni uno mas ni uno menos) y
- no puede acabar tampoco en dígito.

Bien, he creado para ello la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(?=.*[a-zñ])(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉIÓÚ])(?=.*\d){3}(?=.*[\$€\*])[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\$€\*\d]{7,15}(\D$)
```

El asunto es que cumple todos los requisitos salvo el de los tres dígitos, pudiendo introducir más de tres (ya sean seguidos o salteados), y ya no se me escapa, consideraba tenerlo controlado con la expresión: `(?=.*\d){3}`.

Comment: Honestamente, si me exigieran todas estas reglas para crear una clave, probablemente yo terminaría eligiendo no utilizar el sistema. Te recomiendo leer el siguiente artículo: *[Password Rules Are Bullshit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/)*

Comment: Estaba codificando en JavaScript. La verdad es que la clave tiene lo suyo. Anoto esa url que me dejas para consultarla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entre las condiciones que listaste, si tu expresión es correcta, te olvidaste mencionar:

- No puede tener ninguna otra letra o símbolo que no sea los que listaste
  (no están permitidos: `ü`, `.`, `@`, `ç`, etc).
- Debe tener entre 8 y 16 caracteres.

**Cómo exigir los dígitos**

Para poner la condición de que tenga 3, y no más que 3, dígitos en una [inspección positiva](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) (*[positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*), veo que intentaste con:

```
/^(?=.*\d){3}/
```

Repetir una inspección, si bien es sintácticamente correcto, no tiene sentido. Internamente, el motor de expresiones regulares, al terminar de verificar una inspección, vuelve al lugar donde se encontraba en el string antes de intentar la coincidencia. Por ejemplo, en este caso, volvería al inicio del string. Es decir, sería como validar que:

1. Exista 1 dígito luego del inicio del string, y
2. tenga 1 dígito después del inicio, y
3. haya 1 dígito después del comienzo del string.

Claramente, se verifica lo mismo 3 veces. Y sería lo mismo que la expresión regular
`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\d)/` (redundante).

En cambio, la repetición debe estar **dentro** de la inspección. Por ejemplo, con esto nos garantizaríamos que la línea tenga al menos 3 dígitos:

```
/^(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)/
```

que podemos simplificar usando un [grupo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses) (o paréntesis no capturador):

```
/^(?=(?:.*\d){3})/
```

Pero también agregaste la condición de que **no tenga más de 3** dígitos. Para tal fin, tenemos que recorrer todo el string, evaluando que no haya dígitos entre estas repeticiones, y hasta el final.

Podemos utilizar [`\D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-digit), que coincide con un caracter que no es un dígito (es lo mismo que `[^\d]` o `[^0-9]`).

```
/^(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$)/
```

Así, verificamos que, desde el inicio del string, coincida con:

1. `\D*` - cualquier cantidad de caracteres, excepto dígitos.
2. `\d` - seguidos de 1 dígito.
3. `(?:`...`){3}` - Las 2 condiciones anteriores repetidas 3 veces
   (no dígitos + 1 dígito + no dígitos + 1 dígito + no dígitos + 1 dígito).
4. `\D*` - seguido de cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean dígitos.
5. `$` - seguidos del final del string.

**Que no termine en dígito**

Utilizando la estructura de recién, podemos verificar que exista al menos 1 `\D` entre el último dígito y el final, evitándonos la estructura que habías utilizado (`(\D$)`, que dejaba lugar a errores). Es decir, sólo basta con cambiar el último cuantificador:

```
/^(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D+$)/
```

Con `\D+` estamos exigiendo que haya al menos 1 caracter que no sea un dígito antes del final del string (ver [cuantificadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-asterisk), o *[repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)*).

#### Expresión regular

```
/^(?=.*[a-zñ])(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉIÓÚ])(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D+$)(?=.*[$€*])[\da-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ$€*]{8,16}$/
```

[<kbd>Demo en regex101.com</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/IcjzXo/1/)

**Ejemplo en JavaScript**

```js
let clave   = document.getElementById('clave'),
    valido  = document.getElementById('valido'),
    claveok = /^(?=.*[a-zñ])(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉIÓÚ])(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D+$)(?=.*[$€*])[\da-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ$€*]{8,16}$/;

clave.addEventListener('input',function(evt){
  if (claveok.test(clave.value)) {
    valido.innerText = 'Ok';
  } else {
    valido.innerText = 'Inválido';
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="clave">
<span  id="valido"></span>
```

Comment: Si, se pasó comentar algunos detalles má sobre las caracteristicas de la expresión, pero lo que me estaba dando problemas era contabilizar los dígitos. Tengo que ahondar un poco mejor en entender tu explicación, porque funciona, pero no termino de entenderlo. Gracias.

Comment: @acensito - Agregué información en la respuesta para detallar un poco mejor cómo es que funciona. Si hay algo que aún no esté claro, no dudes en comentarlo y sigo agregando más detalle.

Comment: Gracias por la info. El asunto es que los digitos pueden estar de forma continua o salteados (Ej: ej333mplo, 3j3mp1o, ...) pero sólo en un máximo de tres, ni más ni menos y con la salvedad que no ninguna de ellas puede acabar la cadena. Por ello entiendo con tu explicación y modificando, (sin probarlo aún), que debe ser ``(?=(?:\d){3}\D+$)``. Muchas gracias, los ?=, ?: etc no los llego a controlar muy bien del todo.

Comment: @acensito de esa forma, únicamente permitiría 3 dígitos consecutivos al inicio del texto. El `\D*` entre medio es lo que permite que coincida con otros caracteres entre los dígitos. Por ejemplo, para coincidir con `aa1bb2cc3dd` podríamos usar `/^\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*$/`, que es lo mismo que `/^(?:\D*\d){3}\D*$/`. Los `\D*` sin los que van a coincidir con las letras, permitiendo que el regex coincida. Si, además hacernos que no consuma caracteres, tenemos la expresión final de la respuesta: `/^(?=(?:\D*\d){3}\D+$)/`

Comment: @acensito `(?:grupo)` es lo mismo que `(grupo)`, sólo que no graba la coincidencia en memoria

Comment: Y `(?=inspección)` busca que coincida con el patrón, pero luego de coincidir, vuelve el cursor a la posición en la que estaba antes de intentar esa coincidencia. En este caso, siempre se intenta desde el inicio del texto, y se vuelve al inicio del texto. De esa forma, no se consumen caracteres

Comment: Si lees en inglés, te recomiendo http://regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html